# Python function to count the number of unique values in a df column, the output must be a df. NOTE: NOT how many times does the unique value appears

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, unique

I have a very simple question that I have NOT been able to get the answer ‘right’ from many sources (internet and my own NOTES).

I want to count the unique values in each column and the output must be in a DataFrame format:

Example:

```
Column A: Sibusiso, John, Asande, Thamba, Herry, John, Sibusiso, Themba, Siyabonga, Herry, John, Sibusiso, Asande
Column B: 1, 2, 3, 2, 4, 5, 3, 1000, 
Column C: 12, AA, ZZ, 33, 11, 12, AA, BA, 11, ZZ, QA, ED
```

I want my solution to look like this:

```
Column A    7
Column B    6
Column C    9
```

Because there are only 7, 6 and 9 unique values in Column A, Column B, Column C, respectively.

Any solution you might have in mind?

Comment: provide your sample data as code

Answer (score 0):

```
df.apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
```

You can transform it, if you want the row names to be the column names

Answer (score 0):

just do nunique :

```
print(df.nunique())
```